# Доступ к компоненту progressBar формы из другого класса

Tags: c#, progress-bar

Помогите решить задачу:
Есть форма (Form1), которая содержит progressBar1.
Необходимо и пользовательского класса обращаться к бару, увеличивая его значение.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
              public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyFunction();

        }
```

Вот так не работает:

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        public void MyFunction()
        {

           Form1 q = new Form1();
            q.progressBar1.Value+=1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогла ссылка!